# Passing multiple parameters to URL in Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I need to pass multiple parameters in URL. The API URL looks like this https://mydomain/search?campus=selecteddropdownvalue1&subject=selecteddropdownvalue2...

My code only works with one parameter in the API URL, https://mydomain/search?campus= . How to make the multiple parameters work in the request call? Thanks.

```
my react code is:

onSearchSubmit= async (campus,subject)=>{
const response= await axios.get('https:/mydomain/api/search',{
params:{
  campus: campus,
  subject: subject

 }
});

this.setState({Courses: response.data});
```

};

only one parameter in URL works now. when I select second dropdown value, it overwrites the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue arises because of the following,

when you call `onSearchSubmt(campus, subject)` first time, `campus` has a value but `subject` is either null or undefined. And second time `subject` has a value and  `campus` is undefined. You need to pass both values at the same time for it to perform correctly. You `console.log` both values to be sure.

Comment: You are correct. But subject and campus are two components. Do I need to setState for both value in each component? for example, in campus component, state={campus:null, subject:null}.  Thanks.

Comment: How  to pass both values at the same time? My campus and subject are two components.

Comment: keep the axios logic in the parent component, set parent component's state via functions that you pass as props to children component.